# Tabbed Delimited file to SQL queries (bulk update)

Tags: mysql, regex, csv, phpmyadmin

I'm having a huge file (over 2000 lines) of tab separated values stored as a `.txt` file.

I want to use that file to update my database entries within phpmyadmin.

Is there a proper way to convert those lines to sql statements (mysql)?
For example:

```
1   2   nameX   descriptionY    tagKeywords metatagTitleX   metadescriptionX    metaKeywordsX
```

Would become this:

```
UPDATE table SET name=nameX, description=descriptionY, tag=tagKeywords, meta_title=metatagTitleX, meta_description=metadescriptionX, meta_keywords=metaKeywordsX WHERE id=1 AND languague_id=2;
```

I tried using this regex: `^.*?(?=\t)` but this only matches the first occurence found of a line.
And how do 'remember' what the regex found to be able to do a replace?

Or if there's another more easy way let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by create a table:

`CREATE TABLE your_temp_table LIKE your_table;`

Then imported the data (in the newly created table) with the import tab at phpmyadmin saying it was a csv file with tab (\t) separated columns.

Then performed an update query:

```
UPDATE your_table
INNER JOIN your_temp_table on your_temp_table.id = your_table.id
SET your_table.quantity = your_temp_table.quantity;
```

Where al my values were set.

Then deleted the newly created table.

I hope people can use this method in the future :)!

Answer (score 0):

if this text file have all rows with same structure then maybe you can just use tab count and insert query string keywords before each tab and write output file.
or try xls file to put columns with correct string values in row.